# Motion Recognition Manager and motion-Service in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My android app is not working,and the Logcat is showing the following errors:

> 04-29 00:58:24.377 1378-1378/com.example.tencent.coolweather
>   E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService =
>   android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@1ac0fc8c
>
> 04-29 00:58:24.377 1378-1378/com.example.tencent.coolweather
>   E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService =
>   com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@11665fd5
>
> 04-29 00:58:24.377 1378-1378/com.example.tencent.coolweather
>   E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService =
>   com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@11665fd5

Comment: In addition to providing your logcat, please also include the code where the error is occuring.

Comment: could you solve that problem,I face the same problem and need some help??!