# E/ MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService causing app to crash on my android phone

Tags: java, android, xml, sharedpreferences

There is an existing question similar to this one here: [Motion Recognition Manager and motion-Service in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923039/motion-recognition-manager-and-motion-service-in-android)

I'm asking mine because there is a comment requesting the code where the error happens and the code was not provided. It's my first question here, so I hope I'm not doing something wrong or rude.

I'm working on an app which parses RSS feeds and has settings the user can change, like background color, text color, username. These settings are saved in shared preferences.

The app works perfectly in an emulator. In previous iterations, before I added the shared preference functionality, I was able to run the app on my personal Samsung Galaxy s6 phone. Now, it won't run on my phone.

I am displaying the feeds in a `ListView`. Settings are changed from `ListPreferences`.

My logcat looks like this:

```
10/30 10:33:34: Launching app
$ adb push C:\Users\Jennifer\AndroidStudioProjects\RSSAssignment7\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.jennifer.rssassignment7

$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.jennifer.rssassignment7"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.jennifer.rssassignment7
Success


$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.jennifer.rssassignment7/com.example.jennifer.rssassignment7.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 14137 on device samsung-sm_g920w8-1215fc28c4943e05

W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.jennifer.rssassignment7-1/lib/arm64

D/InjectionManager: InjectionManager
D/InjectionManager: fillFeatureStoreMap com.example.jennifer.rssassignment7

I/InjectionManager: Constructor com.example.jennifer.rssassignment7, Feature store :{}
I/InjectionManager: featureStore :{}

W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.example.jennifer.rssassignment7-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.example.jennifer.rssassignment7 rsrc of package com.example.jennifer.rssassignment7

W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.example.jennifer.rssassignment7-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.example.jennifer.rssassignment7 rsrc of package com.example.jennifer.rssassignment7

W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager

E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@8089b26

E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@53d367

E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@53d367

Application terminated.
```

And a code sample, one of the `ListPreferences`:

In preferences.xml:

```
<ListPreference
    android:title="Choose Your Text Color"
    android:summary="We'll save your choice for next time."
    android:key="color"
    android:defaultValue="#000000"
    android:entries="@array/colorArray"
    android:entryValues="@array/colorValues" />
```

In array.xml:

```
<!--color array-->
<string-array name="colorArray">
    <item>Black - black text is not visible on a black background</item>
    <item>Burgundy</item>
    <item>Green</item>
    <item>Blue</item>
    <item>White - white text is not visible on a white background</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="colorValues">
    <item>#000000</item>
    <item>#800020</item>
    <item>#3C8D0D</item>
    <item>#7068FF</item>
    <item>#ffffff</item>
</string-array>
```

In the activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { ...

    TextView titleView, descriptionView;

    titleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleView);

    descriptionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descriptionView);

    //get text color and background color from shared preferences
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    color = prefs.getString("color", "1");

    if(!(color == null)) {
        titleView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(color));
        descriptionView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(color));
    } else {
        titleView.setTextColor(BLACK);
        descriptionView.setTextColor(BLACK);
    }
```

And the xml for the TextViews:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id= "@+id/titleView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id= "@+id/descriptionView"
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linkView"/>
```

I put in the else intending it as a default setting for the first time the app is run, with nothing saved in shared preferences. I'm not certain it's necessary, but I added it when the app was crashing on my phone, thinking that the reason it was crashing was that there were no stored settings.

The app installs on my phone and crashes immediately. I've tried to look at its settings, but there is never anything to change. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app. Again, it won't work on my phone, but it works perfectly on an emulator.

Can anyone offer a suggestion to help get my app running on my phone? Thanks very much.

Comment: Were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems `"1"` in `color = prefs.getString("color", "1");` not a valid color value (Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names: 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'white', 'gray', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'lightgray', 'darkgray', 'grey', 'lightgrey', 'darkgrey', 'aqua', 'fuchsia', 'lime', 'maroon', 'navy', 'olive', 'purple', 'silver', 'teal'.) Take look at [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String))